# How to use replaceitem in 1.17?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I noticed /replaceitem seems to be gone in 1.17 released version, is this not intended or is there another way to use it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it's `/item replace entity [entity] [slot] with [item]` now